# How to insert data i.e. specific column into ggpplot from csv file to obtain said image?

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

So I have a csv file in which I have a column WDL which consists of Win/Draw/Loss (W/D/L). So in my project that is on football, what I want to find is how a title winning team goes on a winning run. For eg. 18 wins in a row. I need to understand how to insert the values into ggplot().

The code in R that was implemented has been given below

```
 library(ggplot2)

#Some test data
set.seed(0)
testdata <- expand.grid(Team=c("Liverpool","Man U","Man City","Leicester", "Wolves"), Game=1:27)
testdata$Result <- sample(factor(c("Win","Draw","Loss"), levels=c("Win","Draw","Loss")), length(testdata[[1]]), 
                          replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4,0.2,0.4))

#plot
ggplot(testdata, aes(x=Game, y=as.numeric(Result), fill=Result)) + facet_grid(Team~., switch="y") +
  geom_tile(colour="grey80", width=1,height=1) + scale_y_reverse(breaks=NULL) +
  ylab("") + scale_fill_manual(values=c(Win="green3",Draw="Orange",Loss="Red"))
```

For example, the WDL column will have data like
W W D W W L W W D D W L L

Hope this image expresses how I've wanted to do it but I can't insert specific data from my csv file.
[WDL Pattern Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS1sv.png)

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether the part you're looking for guidance on is how to load a CSV and get it into format like the test data above, or how to calculate a particular stat (e.g. largest win run) from such data. If the former, we'd need info about the format from the CSV and what you've tried to load it. If the latter, we'd need info about what stat you want, and an example of input with the output you'd expect.

Comment: Do you want to include the subtitle text from the dataframe? What is your expected output for this case?

Comment: So i want the latter part. I want a plot which showcases the winning run. So i have a column which tells me if the result of the particular game was a Win(W) , Draw (D) or Loss (L). I have the input as W W W W W W D W L W W L L  in the csv file. My expected output is similar to the image shown except for the green, red colours will be different for my input as I am showing the trend of previous seasons.  I have a link for the data that i have [link](https://notepad.pw/lq22d9pp) . the output should be like the one on the above image given using ggplot